# Open HTML file whose relative path is known in a browser using C#

Tags: c#, html

On running my console-based C# application it produces a `Results.htm` file at a location `"../../Template/Output/"` and at the end of the program I want to open the `Results.htm` file in a browser.

Currently, `Process.Start("http://www.google.com");` is working but, how do I open a file whose file name and relative path are known?

Should I somehow get the full path of the `Results.htm` file and use that?

If yes, How do I do that?

Any pointers would help.

Comment: Why doesn't `Process.Start("..\..\Template\Output\Results.htm")` work?

Comment: Did you try Process.Start("../../Template/Output/Results.htm")?  It might not be the best for production use.

Comment: I have it in a variable string outPut = "..\..\Template\Output\Results.htm" and I used Process.Start(outPut) and it did not work not sure if that is the right usage.

Comment: Got it.............Process.Start("..\\..\\Template\\Output\\"+projectName+".htm"); worked... thanks a lot guys... I was clueless and now its working like magic.... thanks a lot. Sorry if you think this thread is a waste becasue I did not find the solution on other threads.

Comment: Getting familiar with the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class might be helpful in the scenario you describe. I personally find it quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the FileInfo with the constructor of the relative file

and then see its attribute of FullName